# Angular 8 - How to access the variables of a child component used in the ng-template of a parent

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, ng-template

In the template of a parent component, I'm using a child component in the ng-template like this

```
<ng-template #signalsDialog>
        <div class="dialog">
            <child-selector
                [Id]="parentModel.id"
                [listSource]="parentModel.signals"
                [loadingState]="parentModel.loadingState"
                (closeDropDown)="closeDropdown()">
            </child-selector>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

This #signalsDialog is displayed in the parent component as a CDK Overlay component, like this
[image]

**Problem#1**
When Search succeeded and the list updated in the background, its not updated in the overlay component unless I close and reopen it.

**Problem#2**
If I want to access some variable of child component(like waiting state for search) while its displayed as an overlay, thats not accessible.

Please help me, whether its an **overlay** limitation or something related to **ng-tempalte**.

Comment: look at using @ViewChild() decorator. This can give you access to the methods and properies of your child-selector component at any point in time.

Comment: @SamScholefield Thanks for your Input, but I guess that ViewChild() decorator is helpful to access the properties of child in parent. I want just my child component to refresh its state based on the updated NgRx-store state, which is passed from parent.

Comment: Show your code - not just your template. Stackblitz example is preferred.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarFarooq if the parent component is the one that knows the store state then it can call any method in the child (ngOnInit for example) to refresh the child component accordingly. I use this in partnership with @Input() bindings.